# How to retrieve other child value when a specific child value is known

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image: screenshot]

I wonder if there's any way where when I try to retrieve the specific email, I get the other child value which is the id. For example, I retrieve the louis@gmail.com, I get the id in the database for return. Whenever i tried to access the id, it says cannot resolve symbol id. Intent doesnt work if i put it inside the if()

```
public class loginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CheckBox checkbox;
    EditText email;
    EditText password;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    String emailText;
    String passwordText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        checkbox = findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
    }

    public void confirm(View view) {
        checkAccount();
    }

    private void checkAccount() {
        emailText = email.getText().toString();
        passwordText = password.getText().toString();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        checkBox();

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailText, passwordText).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                if (!checkbox.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "Account signin successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    goToMain(new DataRetriever() {
                        @Override
                        public void onIdFound(String id) {
                            Intent toMain = new Intent(loginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            toMain.putExtra("welcomeId", id);
                            startActivity(toMain);

                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "Account signin failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void goToMain(DataRetriever retriever) {

        DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    String email = String.valueOf(snapshot1.child("email").getValue());
                    if (email.equals(emailText)){
                        String id = String.valueOf(snapshot1.child("id").getValue());
                        retriever.onIdFound(id);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }
    public interface DataRetriever{
        void onIdFound(String id);
    }


    public void checkBox() {
        if (checkbox.isChecked()) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("remember", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("remember", "true");
            editor.apply();

            Intent toMain = new Intent(loginActivity.this, introActivity.class);
            startActivity(toMain);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the `id` come from inside `toMain.putExtra("welcomeId", id);`?

Comment: @AlexMamo `String id` inside the `GoToMain` method it should be declare before oncreate

Answer (score 0):

You mean that you want to get the other childs instead of the current you have, yes it is possible

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
reference.child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String email= snapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);//get email
                //Check if email is the not same
                  if(!email.Equals(EditTextValue){
                   //other value id
                   String id= snapshot.child("id").getValue(String.class);
                  }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there any way where i can retrieve the data outside?

Comment: Yes and it is possible, I edited my asnwer

Comment: Whenever i try to access it, it shows error. Can you help me on how to access it too? Also what i mean in the question is whenever i input certain email, it shows the other child value which is the id. For ex, louis@gmail.com id is Louis; lala@gmail.com id is Lala. How do i get that specific id if i input certain email?

Comment: what error ? please provide the error and check my answer again

Comment: its like the variable cant be access outside the addValueEventListener method. The id variable cant be access, need to create another variable outside the method, which is another different variable that doesnt have the same value

Comment: post your code please, and error for that we can understand where the error came from

Comment: Edited. It says, cannot resolve symbol id

Comment: put the intent inside `if()` and the rest

Comment: The intent doesnt work for some reason

Comment: show the structure of your database,

Comment: I posted the whole code for you to read it, its a bit messy.

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales `valueEventListener` runs on background thread. You have to use interface to check when value is read from database

Comment: @AbuSaeed maybe he got a child before those nodes, thats why `onDataChange` is not trigger

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales I think he wants to read a node named "id" and wants to use it outside later.

Answer (score 0):

Add this interface

```
public interface DataRetriever{
    void onIdFound(String id);
}
```

Replace your `gotoMain` with this

```
public void goToMain(DataRetriever retriever ) {

    DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

    dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot1: snapshot.getChildren()){
                String email = String.valueOf(snapshot1.child("email").getValue());
                if (email.equals(emailText)){
                    String id = String.valueOf(snapshot1.child("id").getValue());
                    retriever.onIdFound(id);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

Call `gotoMain` like below:

```
 goToMain(new DataRetriever() {
        @Override
        public void onIdFound(String id) {
            //do whatever you want to do with id
        }
    });
```

Comment: For some reason, the intent inside goToMain(new DataRetriever()) doesnt work. Nothing happens again. I reedited the code